# I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null" after following a tutorial

Tags: javascript, html

This is my javascript code, but nothing seems wrong too me. My html id is not wrong either. I was following a tutorial on youtube and it worked for the person that did it. Can anyone help me with this?

```
var canvas;
var ctx;

var background;
var width = 300;
var height = 200;

var cloud;
var cloud_x;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    width = canvas.width; //THIS IS WHERE I GET MY ERROR
    height = canvas.height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // init background 
    background = new Image();
    background.src = 'http://silveiraneto.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/forest.png';

    // init cloud
    cloud = new Image();
    cloud.src = 'http://silveiraneto.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/cloud.png';
    cloud.onload = function(){
        cloud_x = -cloud.width;
    };

    return setInterval(main_loop, 10);
}

function update(){
    cloud_x += 0.3;
    if (cloud_x > width ) {
        cloud_x = -cloud.width;
    }
}

function draw() {
    ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);
    ctx.drawImage(cloud, cloud_x, 0);
}

function main_loop() {
    draw();
    update();
}

init();
```

My html

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="640" height="480">Alternative text if browser don't support canvas.</canvas>
```

Comment: It looks like `init()` was called before the `<canvas>` was loaded.

Comment: When does your script run?

Comment: @Musa They are in separate files. I also get that init() is an anonymous function.

Comment: @PM77-1 it runs as soon as the window opens in chrome. Do i need a "window.addEventListener('load',init,false);"?

Comment: anonymous functions do not have names, so init cannot be an anonymous function, also what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: Yes, something like this. You need to make sure that `init()` isn't called before your HTML is fully rendered.

Comment: @Musa I got this in the error when i click an arrow in the console            init @ new 2.js:13                (anonymous function) @ new 2.js:48

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
init();
```

By this line:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

The init function will be called when the `DOM` is ready.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qcqpaz7/)